# Difference between Facebook "Page Likes" and "URL Likes" - updates on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am currently implementing Facebook on an eCommerce store.

I have a Facebook page for the actual store and I also have links on each of the product pages where visitors can "Like" the individual products.

Now, I know that when someone "likes" the actual Facebook Page of the store, they receive status updates whenever that page makes a post on their wall.

Is there any way to integrate this also if someone only likes a product, instead of the entire Page, they also receive status updates of the Page?

Or do they need to like the actual Page in order to receive updates.

I hope someone with experience in integrating this can help me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Building a relationship with a user visiting your page or an opportunity to reach to friends of that particular user.
If the user likes a post, link or an article on your web page this is a one time action and after some time this action will disappear from his/her friends' news feed. And the opportunity to interact with that user one more time will disappear as well. But if that user likes your page so you will have one more fan who will receive your updates every time you post them (Actually this is not always as Facebook news feed algorithm can filter your post).
But what can I suggest is: Put a separate Like Box in your web page to gain more likes for your Facebook page. This like will be more targeted and relevant, as they know what they are doing and they will not be surprised if they see some posts from your page on their news feed. This could be a better experience for your page. 
And secondly put separate like button on each product with correct `meta tags` and if it interests particular users they will go to your web page and if they like it, they will also connect to your Facebook page.